# Need to forumulate UPDATE statement based on corresponding value

Tags: mysql, awk, sed

I have a "key" file (cardinality order) that looks like this:

```
ID
Name
Job
```

Then I have an edited bin.log from an erroneous update statement in the following format:

```
1
'Joe'
'Grocer'
2
'Bill'
'Mason'
```

What I need to do is using the corresponding "key" file, formulate update statements so the result is as follows:

```
update database.table set Name='Joe', Job='Grocer' WHERE ID=1;
update database.table set Name='Bill', Job='Mason' WHERE ID=2;
```

These needs to work for multiple columns of data, however. The first field in the key file will always be a single primary key. In other words, the 'WHERE' clause in the update statement will always utilize this line in the key file. Everything under the first line in the key file are the columns that need to be 'SET' in the order that they occur.

For this example, ID will be the column in the WHERE clause, and 'Name' will be set first to corresponding line in bin.log, and then 'Job', etc., etc., While this example only has three lines in the key file, there can be any number of lines. The first line will always, however, be the column that is used for the ending 'WHERE' piece of the update statement.

Comment: Conceptually I've tried getting line counts from both files and running a while inside a while, but I can't get correct logic. Stumped on getting started, to be honest. I've ran several examples where I knew exactly how many lines I was getting, but this arbitrary amount is causing me some confusion. I've also considered appending text in front of every line and then using awk to paste the fields in different positions but none of those seem like a good idea implementation wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a rough draft of a script that does what you want. If you like it, we can improve upon it for efficiency,style,correctness.

***generate_statement.sh:***

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
read -r -a cnames <<< "$(echo $(cat cnames))"
numcols=${#cnames[@]}

counter=0; sclause=""

while read -r cvalue
do
   if (( $counter == 0 ))
   then
        keys_value=$cvalue
   elif (( $counter == $numcols-1 ))
   then
        sclause="$sclause, ${cnames[$counter]}=$cvalue"
        read -r sclause <<< "$(echo $sclause | sed 's/,//')"
        echo "update database.table set $sclause where ${cnames[0]}=$keys_value;"
        sclause=""
   else
        sclause="$sclause, ${cnames[$counter]}=$cvalue"
   fi
   (( counter = ++counter % numcols))
done <<< "$(cat cvalues)"
```

***cnames:***

```
ID
Name
Job
Height
Weight
```

***cvalues:***

```
1
'Joe'
'Grocer'
60
160
2
'Bill'
'Mason'
61
170
3
'John'
'Engineer'
65
180
4
'Jack'
'Doctor'
69
190
```

***Output:***

```
update database.table set Name='Joe', Job='Grocer', Height=60, Weight=160 where ID=1;
update database.table set Name='Bill', Job='Mason', Height=61, Weight=170 where ID=2;
update database.table set Name='John', Job='Engineer', Height=65, Weight=180 where ID=3;
update database.table set Name='Jack', Job='Doctor', Height=69, Weight=190 where ID=4;
```

Comment: potong and your answer both work exactly like I want them to. I will probably use yours because i can understand what it is doing. I wish I could split the credit between you both but I feel I have to give it to the person who responded first with the correct solution.

Comment: I'm sorry I checked the times again and you were indeed first to respond so i will mark your answer correct.

Comment: That will fail in weird and wonderful ways given various possible input values, environment variables, and directory contents you run it from. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) to understand some, but not all, of the reasons not to do this. And no, I am definitely not suggesting you use a pile of runes following the word `sed` either.

Comment: @user3299633, I don't mind if others get rewarded. These guys have worked for longer time than myself in helping others. I wish to learn awk-ism from Ed.

Comment: It doesn't matter who gets credit for what, the point is that you should not use the above script as it's slow, fragile, etc.. because it's simply the wrong approach. A shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those calls, it is NOT a tool to manipulate text. See that "don't use shell loops" link I provided earlier. This script would be orders of magnitude slower than an awk script, is not portable to other shells, and would fail given various inputs, etc. as I also mentioned earlier. For example try it if the file `cnames` just contains the string `*`.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { a[++m]=$0; next }
    {
        n = ((FNR-1) % m) + 1
        v[n] = $0
    }
    n == m {
        printf "update database.table set %s=%s, %s=%s WHERE %s=%s;\n", a[2], v[2], a[3], v[3], a[1], v[1]
    }
' file bin.log
update database.table set Name='Joe', Job='Grocer' WHERE ID=1;
update database.table set Name='Bill', Job='Mason' WHERE ID=2;
```

If your problem is really [as @blackpen guessed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932574/1745001) then the tweak to make it work would be:

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { a[++m]=$0; next }
{
    n = ((FNR-1) % m) + 1
    v[n] = $0
}
n == m {
    printf "update database.table set"
    for(i=2; i<=n; i++) {
        printf "%s %s=%s", (i>2 ? "," : ""), a[i], v[i]
    }
    printf " WHERE %s=%s;\n", a[1], v[1]
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file bin.log
update database.table set Name='Joe', Job='Grocer' WHERE ID=1;
update database.table set Name='Bill', Job='Mason' WHERE ID=2;
```

Comment: Where is it pulling the two file names? And it looks like this would only work with a specific  number of columns...

Comment: Whtat I mean is there might be more than just Name and Job -- there could be any number of columns like Address, Suite, etc., etc.

Comment: The file requires manual input of columns. For example the user types in ID, Name, Job -- but the binlog that is also included has every column that is available in the table. Based on a count of rows in the first file, it trims the binlog so that only the appropriate information is listed. So before the step to process the update statements, it will already have a "cleaned" binlog file.

Comment: I have no idea what that means in relation to your question, sorry. Again, if you have an example that the script I posted does not work for then edit your question to show it and provide a better description of your requirements in your question.

Comment: The last portion of my question indicates it must be able to accomodate more than just a specific number of columns. Your script will only product output for three columns, not an undetermined number.

Comment: I think he wants to make it work with variable number of columns (with the first column being the primary key).

Comment: Yes clearly he wants to "make it work" but I have no idea what "make it work" means and for some reason the OP is unable or unwilling to show us with an example in his question. Lets say the input file contains 150 "columns" of data. The output he has shown us he wants produced accommodates 3 of those "columns". So now what? His posted expected output has some formatting text to frame those 3 "columns" and has shuffled the order of the input "columns" - is the script supposed to invent additional formatting text and figure out what order the "columns" go in?

Comment: @blackpen For example if he adds a 4th line "Color" to the first file and then corresponding lines Red and Green to his log file. Should the output be `update database.table set Name='Joe', Job='Grocer', Color=Red WHERE ID=1;` or `update database.table set Name='Joe', Job='Grocer' WHERE ID=1 and Color=Red;` or something completely different? THAT is what the OP for some reason is refusing to show us in his question.

Comment: Ed, I apologize I wasn't able to convey what I wanted in my initial description. I wasn't trying to avoid adding detail. I "thought" my description was clear. I'm upvoting your post for taking the time to assist.

Comment: @EdMorton, I took the meaning as "WHERE ID=1" because OP mentioned that as the primary key.

Comment: user3299633 no, your description 100% is not clear. I'm sure in your mind you have some context and background/domain knowledge that makes it clear to you but we don't all have that so why not just edit your question to show what you want? It'll help others searching the archives in future as well as clarify your requirements for the rest of us so we don't have to assume that @blackpen's interpretation of your requirements is correct and use the sample input/output blackpen provided to make up for you not providing it.

Comment: Ed that works great. I really enjoy your clean and easy to read code. Again, I'm sorry I had difficulty explaining what it was I needed.

Comment: I've tried revising my initial description to make it more clear as to what I want. I hope that future users can be assisted with this topic.

Comment: Yes it does help, thanks, but I don't understand why you don't just add a second example with 4 or 5 "columns" to demonstrate your needs - that'd be much clearer. Oh well, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's#.*#s/.*/&=\&/#;1s#$#;h#;1!s#.*#n;&;H#;$s#$#;x;s/^([^\\n]*)\\n(.*)/update.database.table set \\2 WHERE \\1;/;s/\\n/, /gp#' file |
sed -nrf - log
```

Turn the file into a sed script then run it against the log.

Comment: That does exactly what I want. I can't understand it by any means (laughing out loud) but it does work. Maybe in a few years I'll be able to interpret sed better (hopefully).